# Using QGIS Field Calculator to replace backslash?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I actually use the Field Calculator "replace" formula that works very well but I have some '\' caracters in my field that I cannot replace. 
ex : '\naninana' and I want to keep only 'naninana'.

Comment: shouldn't "\n" be a line break?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to remove a `\` in a field, you can escape it as in:

```
replace(fieldname, '\\', '')
```

Or if you wanted to remove `\n`:

```
replace(fieldname, '\\n', '')
```

Comment: It works with replace(fieldname, '\\', '') ! Thanks a lot @larsks